# How to use CNN and LSTM for NLP with BERT embeddings?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the imdb dataset translated into BERT embeddings with dimension 768. So I have 40000 samples of 768 features for training and 10000 samples for validating with the same size of 768. I have tried out dense layers and I have reached about a 85% accuracy with not much problems. But, when it comes to use convs layers and lstms layers I have dimension problems. Another missing concept I have is that I do not know the correr order of those layers. I assume that it should be right at the entrance of the model since those layers are capable of capturing time dependencies and with BERT embeddings those dependencies are learnt. I am using a batch size of 200 reviews. Thanks in advance for any kind of clarification.

I believe that since I am already using BERT embeddings I do not need an input layer with Embeddings type but I am not sure of this, eaither.

DISCLAIMER: After some experiments, I think that One does not need a LSTM layer, nor a CNN. Classification should be done with dense because the embeddings should bring all the contextual information. By that time I was not wise enough (still not being) and maybe I was just trying different approaches

My input training set:

```
np.array(x_train).shape
(40000, 768)
```

And the model I'm using

```
import keras
from keras import models
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Embedding, Bidirectional, Dense, LSTM, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Reshape, TimeDistributed
from keras import optimizers

reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.50, patience=2, verbose=1, mode='auto', cooldown=0, min_lr=0.00001)

early = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

model1 = Sequential()

# CONVS + POOLING LAYERS or RECURRENT LAYERS
# CONVS + POOLING LAYERS or RECURRENT LAYERS

model1.add(Dense(526, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))


model1.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model1.summary()

adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)

model1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history  = model1.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train),
 epochs= 20,
 batch_size = 200,
 validation_data = (np.array(x_val), np.array(y_val)), callbacks = [reduce_lr, early]
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conv1D and LSTM require 3D data.

`np.array(x_train).shape
(40000, 768)`

The correct shape should be `(40000, 768, 1)`

So, reshape your array.

`x_train = x_train.reshpae(-1, 768, 1)`

```
model1 = Sequential()

model1.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')) # input_shape = (768,1)
model1.add(Conv1D(256, 3,  activation='relu'))
# flat
model1.add(Flatten())

model1.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model1.summary()
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Why do you reshape it into 1? Why 1?

Comment: Why temporal dimension should be set to 1? Do you know the answer to this:

I believe that since I am already using BERT embeddings I do not need an input layer with Embeddings type but I am not sure of this, eaither. Am I right?

Comment: I think if *the output bert embeddings have temporal/spatial dependency*, then the temporal dimension should be 768 else 1. Also using 1 temporal dimension doesn't make sense (I just made a general comment in the previous case). Just use 768 temporal dimension (LSTM), or spatial dimension (CNN),1 feature per time-step, spatial dimension.

Comment: So then, how would be the correct reshaping for LSTMs or RNNs? I can not reshape data as .reshape(-1, 768, 768) because it complains about the dimensions.

Comment: No, just keep (768,1) for CNN1D, LSTM both. As I told, the number of feature per time step is 1. A simple example, let's say you have sensor data with 100 length (x, y, z) axis. You will have 100 temporal dimension 3 feature per time-step. In your case, you just have one feature/channel.

Comment: Ok, so that third dimension is like the number of features I want to pass step by step? So it makes sense to pass just 1 and the model should recognise the patterns on those numbers.

Comment: Yes, you can read an intro artcile on CNN/LSTM or documentation on tensorflow site. Should make things more clear.

Comment: Why does one add LSTM layer? Isnt a dense enough? I mean the word embeddings are already cotextualized by their order with the attention mechanism?

Comment: You are completelly right. One does not need a LSTM layer, nor a CNN. Classification should be done with dense because the embeddings should bring all the contextual information. By that time I was not wise enough (still not being) and maybe I was just trying different approaches.